# Dynamic as3 app for mobiles

Tags: android, ios, actionscript-3, mobile, flash

I have a web app based on PHP and AS3. The user enters personal data, and with all that dynamic info, the app generates a swf clip with audio, text and pictures. Everything works fine but I want to be able to play the video on mobiles.

I thought about server-side rendering, and then just encode to mp4, but seems that its not a practical option.

Then I read threads about using AIR and NetStream and StageVideo, but it looks like you can only play the video on your computer not in a server.

Can you point me in the right direction on this matter? What are the options?

Comment: Didn't JWPlayer support something like that ? I might be recalling something wrong though ,but I recommend moving ahead with mp4 or any other non `swf` format, as they're supported natively by most if not all mobile browsers/players.

Comment: I really appreciate you took a time to help me Mostafa. I didn't specify that, but I would likt to avoid bar controls, and also do you think is posible for JWPlay to take variables, files and cue points and combine them all together?

Regards!

Comment: An Air solution would be relevant in you're planning on distributing a standalone app downloadable through the App Store.  As a webpage, it would not work.

Comment: Thank you Atriace. Yeah, actually is not an downloadable app. Is just an script in a web page which display videos. So we can skip the AIR solution right?

Is there an option? Should be, right? For exemple JIBJAB PNP. They use Flash I suppose. Actually the application is very similar to this two... you personalize a video with your variables:

http://www.portablenorthpole.com/home

Comment: Since I still don't have any answer, maybe I should change my question... maybe "is there any way to play a swf in iOS and android"?